# How to format mass data pulled from a database?

Tags: php, html

I am using a PHP script to pull large amounts of entries from a database, it looks like this:

```
foreach($events as $e){ //sets each set of data as a value of $e
$vidID = $e["Test Video YouTube ID"]; //stores each video ID as this variable, so that it can be called when embedding the video
  echo "<br>" . '<iframe width="250" height="140" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $vidID . '?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>' . "<br>" 
  . '<strong> DOC: </strong>' . $e["Axial Cut"] . " " . '<strong> IPM: </strong>' . $e["Inches Per Minute"] . "<br>" . 
  '<strong> WOC: </strong>' . $e["Radial Cut"] . " " . '<strong> FPT: </strong>' . $e["Inch per Tooth"] . "<br>" .
  '<strong> SFM: </strong>' . round($e["Surface Feet per Minute"]) . "<br>"; //each value here is displayed. use the form '$e["Column to be dislplayed"].'
```

This displays each field for the entry I need, then goes to the next entry and does the same, displaying every entry in the database.

My issue is that it only displays them in a vertical line, so what is the best way to format the output in such a way that it displays in a grid, with a set amount of columns?

*EDIT - To clarify, I don't want to use something like a CSS table for this. It limits me in that the data cannot automatically fill into columns, instead each entry would either appear in a single column or I would have to update each field every time the database had a new entry which would be quite tedious. So what is the best way to have data automatically flow into these columns and rows?

Comment: check **Bootstrap** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How do you determine every Nth iteration of a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936242/php-how-do-you-determine-every-nth-iteration-of-a-loop)

Comment: http://jafty.com/blog/how-to-do-something-every-nth-iteration-in-a-php-loop/

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49461024/4508593. It describes how to display an array containing x elements as a html table containing a fixed number of rows or fixed number of columns